# Ufw allow app: ERROR: Need 'from' or 'to' with 'app'

Tags: networking, firewall, vnc, remote-desktop, ufw

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, although this question is probably not specific to Ubuntu but to any system using `ufw`.
I am setting up a rule for VNC vino connections.
I meant to do that via a configured app.
I created `/etc/ufw/applications.d/vino-server` with the following contents

```
[Vino Server]
title = “Vino VNC Server”
description = “Vino - Default Ubuntu VNC server”
ports=5900,5901/tcp
```

and then

```
$ sudo ufw allow app "Vino Server" from 192.168.0.0/24
ERROR: Need 'from' or 'to' with 'app'
```

**How can I solve this error?**

I executed then

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 proto tcp to any port 5900
```

which added one line to the `ufw status` (see below), and finally allowed connection via remmina. So it seems I am ok to connect, and only missing the app-way configuration/allowing.

```
$ sudo nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-19 08:03 -03
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
631/tcp  open  ipp
5900/tcp open  vnc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds

$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5900/tcp                   ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24      <--- THIS LINE ADDED    
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

$ sudo ss -ltnp
State        Recv-Q       Send-Q             Local Address:Port              Peer Address:Port       Process                                          
LISTEN       0            5                      127.0.0.1:631                    0.0.0.0:*           users:(("cupsd",pid=727,fd=7))                  
LISTEN       0            128                    127.0.0.1:6010                   0.0.0.0:*           users:(("sshd",pid=9845,fd=11))                 
LISTEN       0            5                        0.0.0.0:5900                   0.0.0.0:*           users:(("vino-server",pid=6594,fd=12))          
LISTEN       0            4096               127.0.0.53%lo:53                     0.0.0.0:*           users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=704,fd=13))       
LISTEN       0            128                      0.0.0.0:22                     0.0.0.0:*           users:(("sshd",pid=7138,fd=3))                  
LISTEN       0            5                          [::1]:631                       [::]:*           users:(("cupsd",pid=727,fd=6))                  
LISTEN       0            128                        [::1]:6010                      [::]:*           users:(("sshd",pid=9845,fd=10))                 
LISTEN       0            5                           [::]:5900                      [::]:*           users:(("vino-server",pid=6594,fd=11))          
LISTEN       0            128                         [::]:22                        [::]:*           users:(("sshd",pid=7138,fd=4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man ufw`:

```
ufw  [--dry-run]  [rule]  [delete]  [insert  NUM]  [prepend] allow|deny|reject|limit
[in|out [on INTERFACE]] [log|log-all] [proto PROTOCOL] [from ADDRESS  [port  PORT  | app APPNAME ]] 
[to ADDRESS [port PORT | app APPNAME ]] [comment COMMENT]
```

Accordingly, you have to specify `from` first.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 app "Vino Server"
```

Comment: Gheez!!! Trivial. Thanks.